# Can some one give me the Good Example of "Encapsulation" other than Java Bean?

Tags: java, javabeans

For Encapsulation i see lot of examples which points Plain Java Bean (private members & public getters & setters) as example. But i think it's not a good example because having a private varibale with public getter & setter is as same as having public varibale it self. Can some one please help me in this regard ?

Comment: Add some validation code to the public getter and setter, and then it will be a good example.  Having the bare getter and setter there in the first place guarantees binary compatibility when you do decide to add validation to the getter and setter.

Comment: Right, or some side-effect (e.g. logging all changes to particular variable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encapsulation allows you to hide your programming behind a single class so that it is contained but also protected from outside interference.

The example you state above is confusing to you because by creating getters and setters on the same private variable, you are in essence exposing your class (which is a no-no for good OO programming).

Try this example instead:

```
public class Door {
    private boolean locked;
    private boolean open;

    public boolean openDoor() {
        if (locked || open) {
            return false; //You can't open a locked or already open door
        }
        open = true;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Now in this (rather simple) example you are giving your end user a method called openDoor() that will allow them to interact with the door without giving them direct access to certain private variables that in reality control whether your door is open or even able to be opened.

So you will still be interacting with those private variables but now your end user doesn't need to know anything about the mechanics of this door... only that they have an interface (through the openDoor() method) by which to manipulate the object.

Incidentally, encapsulation adds a great benefit to your ability to maintain this Door class in the future. Say, for instance, you have another class (like a Person class) which depends on this openDoor() method. What if you need to add a new variable to the class to represent a second deadbolt variable?

Without encapsulation you would need to edit both the Door class and the Person class that must interact with the new deadbolt variable in order to determine if the door could be opened. But with encapsulation, all maintenance can be kept internal to the Door class. The Person class never needs to know that openDoor() contains different logic than before.

Comment: Thanks DanK for the answer. Could you please help me to understand the Abstraction. Because i feel the code present in the openDoor() method can't it be called as "Abstraction" rather than "Encapsulation" ? please clarify.

Comment: Abstraction is a different concept. Encapsulation describes the compartmentalizing of structures from other structures in order to prevent coupling. Abstraction on the other hand describes separating the description or outline of an object from its actual implementation. A good example would be a car interface. Interfaces are abstract structures - you cannot instantiate them but they define how you must write any code that implements the interface.

Comment: With a car your interface would be a steering wheel, an accelerator pedal and a brake pedal. A blueprint of this setup would be considered the abstract layer and any car that a manufacturer actually builds would be the instance. All instances of a car must follow that basic blueprint (otherwise they aren't really cars but some other type of vehicle). It's the same idea with code - your abstract classes define the classes that implement them but you will never be able to actually instantiate the abstract class. That is abstraction in a nutshell - the separation of the blueprint from the object.

Answer (score 2):

Encapsulation is important for several reasons :

- to hide implementation details by setting a private/protected scope on some attributes/methods
- most often, to ensure the consistency of the data ecapsulated. For example, let's assume you're writing a class with a attribute `int myInt` with the constraint that myInt should always be positive. If you decale myInt as a public attribute, the user is free to set it a negative value an break the consistency constraint whereas this simple code protects the state of the object :

  ```
  private myInt = 0;
  public void setMyInt(int value) {
      if (value < 0) 
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("myInt should be positive");
      myInt = value;
  }
  ```
- sometimes you want to delay the evaluation of an attribute (kind of a lazy attribute) so you set its value to null in the constructor and then you provide a getter which computes it the first time and then behaves just like a "normal" getter :

  ```
  //delayed attribute
  private List<User> users = null;
  public List<User> getUsers() {
       if (users == null) 
           users = someMethodWithHighComputationCost();
       return users;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

```
private boolean a = true;

public boolean getA(){
  return a;
}

public void setA(boolean a){
  this.a = a;
}
```

You can't access the 'private' varibale from another class but you can access the public varibales.

Comment: This is exactly what OP said in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulation in Java or object oriented programming language is a concept which enforce protecting variables, functions from outside of class, in order to better manage that piece of code and having least impact or no impact on other parts of program due  to change in protected code. Encapsulation in Java is visible at different places and Java language itself provide many construct to encapsulate members.

Encapsulation is the technique of making the fields in a class private and providing access to the fields via public methods. If a field is declared private, it cannot be accessed by anyone outside the class, thereby hiding the fields within the class.

Example:
Let us look at an example that depicts encapsulation:

```
public class Employee{

   private String name;
   private int age;

   public int getAge(){
      return age;
   }

   public String getName(){
      return name;
   }

   public void setName(String newName){
      name = newName;
   }

   public void setIdNum( String newId){
      idNum = newId;
   }
}
```

The public methods are the access points to this class' fields from the outside java world. Normally, these methods are referred as getters and setters. Therefore any class that wants to access the variables should access them through these getters and setters.

Benefits of Encapsulation:

1. A class can have total control over what is stored in its fields.
2. The fields of a class can be protected (read-only or write-only)
3. The users of a class do not need to know how the class stores its
   data